# How to specify "if two variables are missing"?

Tags: r, if-statement, missing-data

In the dataset “df”, I want to mark the rows as “bad’’ if any variable is missing or check=0.

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(10, 11, NA, NA, 13),
                 col2 = c(9, NA, NA, 7, 6), check = c(1,0,1,0,0))

if (is.na(df$col1)|is.na(df$col2)|(df$check == 0)){

  df$flag = "bad"

  }else{

  df$flag == "good"
}
```

The code doesn’t work, and the warning message is:

> Warning message: In if (is.na(df$col1) | is.na(df$col2) | (df$check ==
>   0)) { :   the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will
>   be used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `rowSums`

```
df$flag <- ('Good', 'Bad')[(rowSums(is.na(df[1:2])) > 0 | df$check == 0) +1]
```

---

Or using `ifelse`

```
df$flag <- with(df, ifelse(is.na(col1)|is.na(col2)|check == 0, "bad", "good"))
```